# export selected rows mysql myphpadmin not the whole table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export, row

I have trawled the forums for what should be a very simple thing to do, but I am in myphpadmin, trying to select specific rows from a data table in a mysql database. I click on the table and in the view, select the check box for the specific rows I wish to export (as sql), with the intent of then importing them into another table.

The steps I follow are:

1. Click on the table and add a tick (click select) to the four rows I wish to selet
2. Click EXPORT
3. Leave it as the custom/default settings - click GO (to create a .sql file for import)

Each time I've tried this, even customising settings, it exports the whole table.

Can anyone help - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you clicking the 'export' at the bottom of the table?

Answer (score 4):

There are three Export buttons:

[image]

Klick the green one.

After that I had only the two selected rows in the dump file:

```
INSERT INTO `actor` (`actor_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `last_update`) VALUES
(7, 'GRACE', 'MOSTEL', '2006-02-15 03:34:33'),
(8, 'MATTHEW', 'JOHANSSON', '2006-02-15 03:34:33');
```

Answer (score 0):

im guessing you are clicking the 'wrong' export link
there are at least 3 export links in myPhpAdmin, the one you want is immediately under the table and in the section labelled 'with selected'

**not** at the top of the page or **not** in the section that says Query results operations