# Export selected column(s) in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, export

Anyone know how to export the SQL from only a selected column or columns?

Seems the info from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62492569/553663) previous post isn't relevant anymore?

Here's a screenshot from the latest version of PHPMyAdmin, and I see no "export" link at the bottom after selecting a row that I want to export:

[image]

My current version of PHPMA is `Version information: 5.2.1 (up to date)`

Addition:

After a closer look, it appears that you can only export the row (as in the link to the previous answer shows) if it already as data in it; mine doesn't (fresh DB) and I want to export the row's structure for import into another (older, non-fresh) DB.

Update:

Turns out I was getting my P's and Q's mixed up terminology-wise (and view-wise), but if anyone is still aware of a way in PHPMA to check the boxes next to a column(s) in the structure/definition view, and export only their SQL, I wanna know! :p

Comment: You're in the wrong screen. You're viewing the table definition, not the table contents like in the other question.

Comment: You can still export the table if it's empty. When you import it, you'll get an empty table with the same structure.

Comment: @Barmar If I export this entire table, and then try importing it into a "dirty" db missing only that row, will it mess up anything in the DB I'm importing into? I specifically just want to import only this row and it's definitions into the older DB where only that row doesn't exist.

Comment: What do you mean by "that row"? I thought you said the table has no data in it.

Comment: @Barmar I have 2 DB's; one "old" with data in it, but missing the "Scope" row, that exists in the "new" DB with no real data in it. Now I want to simply export the SQL structure for that "scope" row in the table from the New DB, and import just that "scope" row (structure) into the Old DB. Is there no easy way in PHPMA? Seems I have to export the entire table, edit the export and then import it. Or manually hand create the scope row in the old BD using the info as seen in the New DB.

Comment: Ah, the problem is that your terminology is wrong. Scope is a column, not a row.

Comment: To add a column to an existing table you have to use the `ALTER TABLE` command, you can't do it with export and import.

Comment: @Barmar "Ah, the problem is that your terminology is wrong. Scope is a column, not a row". Oops, you're right. Looking at the structure view it looks like a row. lol.

Comment: Damn, it'd be nice if PHPMA allowed just checking the boxes for columns, and doing an export of the SQL structure for just those selected columns then. Are you aware of any cline that can do that?

Comment: In PhpStorm (or any other JetBrains IDE), when you add a column to a table, there's a window where it shows the `ALTER TABLE` command that implements it. You can copy and paste from this to make the same change to another DB.

Comment: You can also export the table structure as DDL. Then just copy the line for that column into your own ALTER TABLE command.